# Access network folder with credential always fail

Tags: .net, vb.net

I'm pretty sure that my username and password is correct. I try to access manually with Explorer with success, but somehow this code always return "the user name or password is incorrect".

**Edited:**

```
Try
    Dim theNetworkCredential As NetworkCredential = New NetworkCredential("Ucrit", "ucrit123", "LABCOM21")
    Dim theNetCache As CredentialCache = New CredentialCache
    'theNetCache.Add(New Uri("\\192.168.0.21"), "Basic", theNetworkCredential)
    theNetCache.Add("\\192.168.0.21", "Basic", theNetworkCredential)

    Dim dir As New DirectoryInfo("\\192.168.0.21\prerequisites")
    For Each fi As FileInfo In dir.GetFiles("*.*")
        TextBox1.AppendText(fi.Name & Environment.NewLine)
    Next
Catch ex As IOException
    MsgBox(ex.Message)
End Try
```

Comment: Assuming "LABCOM21" is the domain name, I think you should use [the constructor that takes 3 arguments](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.networkcredential.-ctor?view=netframework-4.8#System_Net_NetworkCredential__ctor_System_String_System_String_System_String_): `New NetworkCredential("user", "password", "domain")`.

Comment: Yup, and it's still the same. I use both Windows 10.

Comment: This code doesn't make sense. You're not using the `CredentialCache` anywhere. That `CredentialCache.Add()` method doesn't exist. `CredentialCache` cannot add `NetworkCredentials` for `Basic` auth: in this case, you just initialize a new `NetworkCredentials` object or you use the `Basic` auth key with Base64 Encoded UserId and Password separated by a colon. E.g., `[WebRequest].Headers.Add(HttpRequestHeader.Authorization, "Basic " + Convert.ToBase64String(Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes($"{UserId}:{Password})))`